# how to use Tornado to post something to Facebook

Tags: facebook-graph-api, oauth-2.0, tornado, publish-subscribe

[tornado](https://github.com/facebook/tornado) accepts *OAuth1, 2* and *OpenID*, and from search in *SO*: *OpenID* is just to *login*, *OAuth* is to tell other service (for example *Facebook*): **ok, come to my account, and use what i give you the permission to use**.

so because of this, how to make a simple "hello world" print in my *Facebook* wall, because if this will work, then one will avoid using a pubsub in his application, and let Facebook display notification (since there is a great chance that a user have Facebook account).

NB: [the example](https://github.com/facebook/tornado/tree/master/demos/facebook) the ships with Tornado is to "how to see *my* notification from localhost"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here is how, you need this: [Python-Facebook SDK](https://github.com/pythonforfacebook/facebook-sdk) and you add this to the facebook example, dont know if it is non blocking, but i see the `self._on_stream` which i think it's a callback, so it is non-blocking?

```
import facebook 

class MainHandler(BaseHandler, tornado.auth.FacebookGraphMixin): 
    @tornado.web.authenticated 
    @tornado.web.asynchronous 
    def get(self): 
        self.facebook_request("/me/home", self._on_stream, access_token=self.current_user["access_token"]) 
    a = self.current_user["access_token"] 
    print a # for debug
    graph = facebook.GraphAPI(a) 
    graph.put_object("me", "feed", message="I am writing on my wall!")
```

NB: **you can post a message only one time in 5 minutes**